# Ошибка импорта cookies из http

Tags: python, cookie

Выводит ошибку при импорте cookies. Пробовал `from http import cookies` и `import http.cookies`.
Сам `http` без ошибок работает. (использую Debian 16.04 LTS)

Comment: from http impoty cookies а ты точно impoty написал, если это так замени на import

Comment: Извиняюсь, ошибка в самом вопросе, а не в проблеме

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки

Comment: скопируй трейс ошибки в вопрос, используешь Python 3 или 2, как называется твой модуль с кодом, не `http.py`?

Comment: importError: cannot import name cookies

Comment: Может  поможет, но ошибка появляется если вводить "python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000"